# Angular JSON Editor

Tags: angular, jsoneditor

I have requirement to implement a JSON Editor just like the JSON editor in the AWS cloud.

The Editor Should able be able to validate any error's on, provide which line the error's
all the features which is available on AWS JSON editor

How do I approach creating Custom JSON Editor?

Answer (score 0):

There is a npm package called [jsoneditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsoneditor) which may be what you need.

You can install it on your project with `npm i jsoneditor`